# using aldeed:autoform I get access denied

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm trying to use autoform with meteor validatedmethod simple schema and collection2. However when I enter values in the textfields I get:

```
undefined error:403
errorType:"Meteor.Error"
message:"Access denied [403]"
reason:"Access denied"
stack:"Error↵    at Connection._livedata_result http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js`
```

My code uses the following template:

```
{{#autoForm collection=club id="insertClubs" type="insert"}}
<fieldset>
  <legend>Add a Club</legend>
  {{> afQuickField name='name'}}
  {{> afQuickField name='number'}}
  {{> afQuickField name='updated'}}
  {{> afQuickField name='created'}}
</fieldset>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

then I'm using an event helper to listen to the submit and invoke a validatedmethod:

```
submit .btn btn-primary'(event, instance) {
  console.log('test');

  insert.call( {
    name: 'test',
    number: 3,
    updated: new Date(),
    created: new Date()
  }, (err, res) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

and this is the insert call itself:

```
export const insert = new ValidatedMethod({
name: 'Clubs.methods.insert',
validate: Clubs.simpleSchema().validator(),
run(newClub) {
  // In here, we can be sure that the newClub argument is
  // validated.
 console.log('insert new club');
if (!this.userId) {
  throw new Meteor.Error('Clubs.methods.insert.not-logged-in',
    'Must be logged in to create a club.');
}

Clubs.insert(newClub)
}
});
```

I think that this setup does not actually invoke my insert method as I don't see the console.log but meteor comes back with the error. Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trying I came across the attribute meteormethod and the type attribute. Configuring this seems to invoke my mdg validated method and takes care of authorization so it seems. See the following that shows how to make use of this:

```
  {{#autoForm collection=club id="insertClubs" type="method" meteormethod="Clubs.methods.insert"}}
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Add a Club</legend>
    {{> afQuickField name='name'}}
    {{> afQuickField name='number'}}
    {{> afQuickField name='updated'}}
    {{> afQuickField name='created'}}
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
  {{/autoForm}}
```

For additional details see: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#non-collection-forms